# Derivatives of Trigonometric functions and Tangent lines

Tags: calculus, derivatives

a.)Find an equation of the tangent line to the curve
$y=x \cos x$ at the point $(\pi,-\pi)$
b.)Illustrate part (a) by graphing the curve and the tangent line on the same screen.
Answer: $y=-x$

Comment: And what about this is giving you trouble?

Comment: @PaulSinclair The trig functions confuse me. I did a similar question before without trig functions.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, every tangent line is a straight line, and can therefore be represented by an equation on the form
$$
t(x) = kx + t(0),
$$
where k denotes the slope. For every point on the curve $y(x) = x\cos(x)$, there is a tangent with slope given by the derivative with respect to $x$.

So, in your case the derivative with respect to $x$ is (Use the product rule!)
$$
y'(x) = \cos(x) -x\sin(x),
$$

which leads to
$$
y'(\pi) = \underbrace{\cos(\pi)}_{=0} -\pi \underbrace{\sin(\pi)}_{=1} = -\pi,
$$
which means that the slope of the tangent line must be $k = -\pi$.

Now, all we have to do is to determine $t(0)$. Since we know that the tangent line passes through the point $(\pi,-pi)$, we get the following
$$
t(x) = -\pi x + t(0) \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad -\pi = -\pi \cdot \pi + t(0) ,
$$
which leads to $t(0) = \pi(\pi-1)$ and the equation for the tangent line becomes
$$
t(x) = -\pi x + \pi(\pi-1).
$$